# Website homepage as a directory. Running joomla and wordpress side to side

Tags: wordpress, joomla

Hope you can help me with this.

We got joomla in my root folder, thats our default website now.

We have just installed wordpress inside a subfolder 'wp'

Now we want to point our homepage (just our homepage alone) to show the wordpress content eg: www.xyz.com will show content from www.xyz.com/wp while we want url in the browser to show just www.xyz.com

Thats the only change we want to do.

Rest of what we had till now, all the urls, functioning for joomla will remain as it is. So only the joomla root homepage will be replaced by wordpress homepage

Also all other joomla and wordpress urls will work as it is.

So we just want the homepage alone to point to the wordpress mainpage. Currently it is using the joomla homepage.

Is this possible? Will this cause any problems ?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, it is easier to move around a Joomla website than a Wordpress website: the internal links in Joomla are relative links; I came across quite a number of absolute links when moving Wordpress sites.

Therefore, I'd recommend doing it the other way around: Have the Wordpress site sit in the root of your website and move the Joomla site to a subdirectory.

Comment: Oh, thanks for your suggestion.
That's not feasible at this moment.
Is it still possible to accomplish this with joomla in root and WP as a subdirectory ?
All I want is the current joomla homepage to wordpress homepage instead of Joomla. Rest remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the job

RewriteRule ^$  http://localhost/xyz/ [L]

or

RewriteRule ^$  /xyz/ [L]

This will also mask the url.